# Facade or Adapter design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

We have the following scenario.

A web URL is exposed and we want to get and post requests to it in order to receive
information about a user.

e.g. http://example.com/getBalance?userid=1234&username=example

The plan is to create a class that will have a number of methods that will be like

```
public class ClassA {
  public int getBalance(string userId, string userName){
     URL url= new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    return in.readLine()) 
  }
  ...
}
```

And then use this class to make the http calls.

```
ClassA a = new Class();
a.getBalance(tdks123, name1);
```

Is this scenario a Facade pattern or an adapter pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually **Session Facade** design pattern ( J2EE design patterns). and in plain old patterns it is subset of Facade pattern.

Session facade pattern is used when :

> You want to expose business components and services to remote clients.

RESTful web service is good example of session facade.

More info on [Session Facade](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/SessionFacade.htm)

Comment: I agree with what you say. However, could you provide an explanation why this does not fall under the Adapter pattern?

Comment: Which class here will work nas Adapter? Will it be A?

Comment: Yes. ClassA would be the adapter. the argument is that it adapts the exposed API to your application and the the Facade is essentially used to combine the API calls. E.g. for the updateBalance http request you can combine a get and then an update into on method in the Facade.

Comment: Incompatibility is essence of adapter design pattern. Where do you see Incompatible part  between request and response in above example?